# How to Iterate Observable response object from component in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I calling the service from Component class and getting Observable (Customers) Object as response. 
If i use 
`<div *ngFor="let cust of customerDetailsItem">` `{{cust.id}}` `</div>` then i am getting the values. but if i want use that observable response in component then it showing "`Undefined`".

```
    constructor(public service:ViewListCustomerServiceService) {
    this.service.getCustomerItemList().subscribe(lst =>this.customerDetailsItem=(lst));
console.log(this.customerDetailsItem);    //Showing Undefined.
  }
```

because i want "`customerDetailsItem`" for assign data to `Json` object in Component class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object `this.customerDetailsItem` will be undefined until you get a response from the subscription. So what you can do is execute the code that is necessary after you receive the `lst`.

```
constructor(...) {
    this.service.getCustomerItemList()
        .subscribe(lst=>this.initialize(lst));
}

initialize(lst: any) {
   this.customerDetailsItem = lst;
   // from now on your object will be set
}
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much. its Working for me,

Comment: Hi Sir, actually i am using "ng2-smart-table". i want to pass "customerDetailsItem" as table data(to @Input source) if i  send by doing above solution then also table is showing empty. if i pass data manually then only its showing. eg:data:CustomerDetailsItem[]=[
    {

      id:1,

      "name":"Customer 1",

      "details":"Customer 1",

      "active":false

    },

    {

      "id":2,

      "name":"Customer 2",

      "details":"Customer 2 details goes here",

      "active":false

    }
]

Comment: Try using an *ngIf="customerDetailsItem" on the smart-table element, otherwise I don't really know without a bigger code sample

Comment: Sir i think as you told in 1st answer, the smart-table Component is loading before Service response so, the @Input data; is injecting by "Undefined".if so, then Please suggest me how to stop loading "smart-table" component until we we get service Response

Comment: As I said before, add the *ngIf to the element `<ng2-smart-table *ngIf="customerDetailsItem" [settings]="settings" [source]="customerDetailsItem"></ng2-smart-table>`